# Elasticsearch searching and sorting across 2 models

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 models: `Products` and `Skus`, where a `Product` has one or more `Skus`, and a `Sku` belongs to exactly one `Product`.  They have the following columns:

```
Product: id, title, content, category_id
Sku:     id, product_id, price
```

I'd like to be able to display 48 products per page across various search and sort configurations, but I'm having trouble translating this to elasticsearch.

For example, it's not clear to me how I would search on `title` while sorting the relevant results by the lowest-priced `Sku` for each `Product`.  I've tried a few different things, and closest has been to index everything as belonging to the `Sku`, then searching like so:

```
size: '48',
aggs: { 
  group_by_product: { 
    terms: { field: 'product_id' } 
  }
},
filter: { 
  and: [{
    bool: { 
      must: { range: { price: { gte: 0, lte: 50 } } }
    },{
    bool: { 
      must: { terms: { category_id: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] } }
    }
  }]
},
query: {
  fuzzy_like_this: {
    fields: [ 'title', 'content' ],
    like_text: 'Chair',
    fuzziness: 1 
  }
}
```

But this gives 48 matching `Skus`, many of which belong to the same `Product`, so my pagination is off if I try to combine them after the search.

What would be the best way to handle this use case?

**Update**

Trying with the nested method, using the following structure:

```
{ 
  size: '48',
  query:
    { bool:
      { should:
        { fuzzy_like_this: 
          { fields: [ 'title' ],
            like_text: 'chair',
            fuzziness: 1 },
      },
      { must: 
        { nested: 
          { path: 'skus',
            query: 
              { bool: 
                { must: { range: { price: { gte: 0, lte: 100 } } }
              } 
          } 
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 
},
sort: 
  { _score: 'asc',
    'skus.price': 
      { nested_path: 'skus',
        nested_filter: 
          { range: { 'skus.price': { gte: 0, lte: 100 } } },
        order: 'asc',
        mode: 'min' 
      } 
  } 
}
```

This is likely closer, but still not sure how to format it.  The above gives products ordered by price, but seems to completely disregard the search field.

Comment: The approach of including the product inside the sku is the correct one. Where I believe it can be improved is the aggregation part. What you actually need is the number of buckets to be 48, not the number of documents. Because the buckets represent the products. Regarding pagination, for aggregation [this is not possible atm](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915).

Comment: Have you tried `nested` objects where the skus are the `nested` ones?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes I have tried nesting skus under products, but couldn't figure out the proper sorting on price that way.  If bucket pagination is not possible, then it seems like that would rule out the aggregation approach?

Comment: Kind of, yes. What issues did you have with `nested` and price sorting?

Comment: I couldn't get it to sort within the search results.  i.e. I could get results ordered by relevance searching on the Product model and filtered by price on the Sku model, but not the search results sorted by price.

Comment: The filter that you used in the query itself, have you put it as well in the sorting part? For nested sorting, [this is required](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html), if you want the sorting to happen on the results that matched: _"Why do we need to repeat the query conditions in the nested_filter? The reason is that sorting happens after the query has been executed."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [paginating aggregation results is not possible](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html), even though the approach of including the `sku` inside the `product` is a good one, I would go with `nested` objects depending on the requirements for queries.

As an example query:

```
GET /product/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "whatever",
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "prefix_length": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "skus",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "skus.price": {
                  "gte": 11,
                  "lte": 50
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "skus.price": {
        "nested_path": "skus",
        "order": "asc",
        "mode": "min"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this out now and will let you know how it goes

Comment: Still not quite able to get it working.  I'm using fuzzy search on the title, so please look at my updated code from the question and see if you can spot how to fix the query.

Comment: In your updated query you need to have "skus.price", because it's a nested filter.

Comment: Something like this: `{ must: { range: { skus.price: { gte: 0, lte: 100 } } }`

Comment: I did, with something similar.  I'm using `sort: { 'skus.price': { nested_path: 'skus', mode: 'min', order: 'asc' } }` instead of the sort you have above, and I have `match: { title: { query: 'whatever', fuzziness: 1, prefix_length: 3 }` inside of the `must` array also (no `should` array).  If you can add these changes to your answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, in this case, it should be ok because you don't have a filter on the nested objects inside the main query. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have the `sort` from my comment above as the only `sort` (i.e. without the first `_score: 'asc'`, and the `match: title` was in addition to the nested `match`, not replacing it.